# Checkboxes (flags) using cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, frontend, local-storage

How do I save the status of checkboxes and tasks to cookies using localStorage?
I need that when the page is reloaded, the user name and the status of the checkboxes, as well as the todo of the list, are stored in cookies
As I understand it, I need to use classes and save the value of the checkboxes in them, as well as the tasks themselves. But I'm starting to get confused in the code and don't really understand how to do it

```js
let tasks = document.querySelector(".tasks");

document.body.onload = () => {
    let name = prompt("Привет! Как я могу обращаться к тебе?");
    let helloBlock = document.querySelector(".helloUser");
    var text = "ToDoList!"; // Ваш текст
    helloBlock.innerHTML = "Привет " + name + "! Это - твой список дел, или как сейчас модно говорить - твой персональный ";
    var delay = 100; // Скорость печатания
    var elem = document.querySelector(".todotext"); // id элемента для вывода результата

    var print_text = function (text, elem, delay) {
        if (text.length > 0) {
            elem.innerHTML += text[0];
            setTimeout(
                function () {
                    print_text(text.slice(1), elem, delay);
                }, delay
            );
        }
    }

    print_text(text, elem, delay);
    setInterval(function () {
        elem.innerHTML = "";
        print_text(text, elem, delay);
    }, 4 * 1000);

    document.querySelector(".inputTasks").onkeypress = (event) => {
        let taskStr = document.querySelector(".inputTasks").value;

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if (taskStr == "") {
                alert("Вы ничего не ввели.");
                return;
            }
            let divTask = document.createElement("div");
            divTask.className = "task";

            let checkBox = document.createElement("input");
            checkBox.type = "checkbox";
            checkBox.className = "checkBox";

            let trash = document.createElement("div");
            trash.className = "trash";
            trash.innerHTML = "️";

            let task = document.createElement("div");
            task.className = "taskName";
            task.innerHTML = taskStr;

            divTask.appendChild(checkBox);
            divTask.appendChild(task);
            divTask.appendChild(trash);
            tasks.appendChild(divTask);

            document.querySelector(".inputTasks").value = "";

            checkBox.addEventListener('change', event => {
                if (checkBox.checked) {
                    task.classList.add("complete");
                }
                else {
                    task.classList.remove("complete");
                }
            });

            trash.addEventListener('click', event => {
                if (confirm("Вы точно хотите удалить задачу: " + taskStr + " ?")) {
                    divTask.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="helloUser"></div>
        <div class="todotext"></div>
        <input type="text" class="inputTasks" placeholder="Введите задачу">
        <div class="tasks"></div>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I suggest you to translate everything in English (comments and variables in the code). It will be much simpler to read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet to save user name, todo and status of checkbox into localstorage and cookies.

```js
// fire when everything is loaded
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // variable to store user name
  let name = null;
  // function to validate user name and insert into dom
  const getUserName = () => {
    // ask user name
    name = prompt("Hello! How can I address you?");
    // if name is null or name length is less or equals to zero or name only contains white spaces then this will fire
    if (!name || name.length <= 0 || /^\s+$/g.test(name)) {
      // alert user that he/she didn't enter a name
      alert("You didn't enter a valid name!");
      // call getUserName function
      getUserName();
    } // else this will fire
    else {
      // get helloUser by its id
      const helloUser = document.getElementById("helloUser");
      // set helloUser innerText to given backtick string
      // we can insert a variable in backtick string by using ${}
      helloUser.innerText = `Hello ${name}! This is your to-do list, or as it's fashionable these days, your personal.`;
    }
  }; // call getUserName function
  getUserName();

  // arrow function to show typing animation
  const showAnimation = () => {
    // get todoText by its id
    const todoText = document.getElementById("todotext");
    // set todoText innerText to blank
    todoText.innerText = "";
    // create a array from string
    const todoAnimation = Array.from("ToDoList!");
    // typing speed delay
    const todoAnimationDelay = 100;
    // index to iterate characters of todoAnimation
    let index = 0;
    // a setInterval for typing animation
    const animation = setInterval(() => {
      // get character from todoAnimation by using index
      // immediately increment index by one
      const character = todoAnimation[index++];
      // if character is present then
      // append character into todoText innerText
      // else clear animation interval
      character ? (todoText.innerText += character) : clearInterval(animation);
    }, todoAnimationDelay);
  }; // call showAnimation function
  showAnimation();
  // set interval for typing animation
  setInterval(showAnimation, 4000);

  // get inputTasks by its id
  const inputTasks = document.getElementById("inputTasks");
  // add keypress event on inputTasks
  inputTasks.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    // if event key equals to Enter and event keyCode equals to 13 then this will fire
    if (event.key === "Enter" && event.keyCode === 13) {
      // get tasks by its id
      const tasks = document.getElementById("tasks");
      // get inputTasks value
      const inputTasksValue = inputTasks.value;
      // if inputTasksValue less or equals to zero then
      if (inputTasksValue.length <= 0) {
        // alert user that task is not defined
        alert("You didn't enter anything.");
        // return back
        return;
      }
      // create div and input elements
      const divTask = document.createElement("div"),
        checkBox = document.createElement("input"),
        trash = divTask.cloneNode(true),
        task = divTask.cloneNode(true);
      // set divTask class attribute to task
      divTask.setAttribute("className", "task");
      // set checkBox class attribute to checkBox
      checkBox.setAttribute("className", "checkBox");
      // set checkBox type attribute to checkbox
      checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
      // utility arrow function to save details in storages.
      const saveDetails = (checkBoxStatus) => {
        // convert user name, todo and checkBox.checked into string by usint JSON.stringify
        let userData = JSON.stringify({
          name,
          todo: inputTasksValue,
          checkBox: checkBoxStatus,
        });
        // add userData into localStorage and cookie
        localStorage.setItem("userData", userData);
        document.cookie = `userData=${userData}; Path=/; SameSite=None; httpOnly: true; Secure=false;`;
      };
      // call saveDetails function with checkBox checked
      saveDetails(checkBox.checked);
      // add change event on checkBox
      checkBox.addEventListener("change", () => {
        // utility class name
        const utilityClass = "complete";
        // if checkBox is checked then
        // add utilityClass else remove utilityClass
        checkBox.checked
          ? task.classList.add(utilityClass)
          : task.classList.remove(utilityClass);
        // call saveDetails function with checkBox checked
        saveDetails(checkBox.checked);
      });
      // set trash class attribute to trash
      trash.setAttribute("className", "trash")
      // set trash innerText to icon
      trash.innerText = "";
      // add click event on trash
      trash.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // confirm user about delete task
        const finalCheck = confirm(
          `Are you sure you want to delete the task: ${inputTasksValue} ?`
        );
        // if finalCheck is true then remove divTask else do nothing
        finalCheck ? divTask.remove() : null;
      });
      // set task class attribute to taskName
      task.setAttribute("className", "taskName");
      // set task innerText to inputTasksValue
      task.innerText = inputTasksValue;
      // append checkBox, task and trash into divTask
      divTask.append(checkBox, task, trash);
      // append divTask into tasks
      tasks.appendChild(divTask);
      // set inputTasks value to blank
      inputTasks.value = "";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>ToDoList</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
      <div id="helloUser" class="helloUser"></div>

      <div id="todotext" class="todotext"></div>

      <input
        type="text"
        id="inputTasks"
        class="inputTasks"
        placeholder="Enter a Task"
      />

      <div class="tasks" id="tasks"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I respect your language but i wrote everything in english because when other will see this question they have to understand what is happening.

I am not 100% sure that this work!
When using stack snippet its not working but in localhost it works fine! I tested it with live server.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry, I understand English well
Thank you very much for your help! Everything works!

Comment: Good to see that everything is fine now!